# R - dygraphs with DT and shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dygraphs, dt

Here is my first question.
[Here is the graph. Why my graph does not show numbers on each lines and how can I change left side axis to display numbers rather than exponential sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NBCS.jpg)

In addition, I have some questions about **DT**, **dygraphs** and **shiny**.  
 1. I have already read my csv data in R and simply run the **dygraphs** as the attaching image. However, if I want my image to have some numbers on lines when my mouse stay on it, how can I do? ***SOLVED***  
 2. Also, I want to change the y axis to display numbers rather than exponential sign.  ***SOLVED***  
 3. I have an idea about using **shiny** to show my excel data. Thus, I use **DT** package with datatable function. Moreover, how can I combine **DT** and **dygraphs** in **shiny**. I mean when I click the datatable and select some rows or columns, there will show the dynamic line graph. Maybe there are other useful and convenient packages? 
4. Where can I learn some reference about shiny combining with **DT**.

following is my test.csv data input to R.

```
   year month company      wp wn       ep en       pa pan npa npan
1  2015     1      Ch 6497985  1  1471586  2  4833118   3   0    0
2  2015     1      SK     350  1        0  0        0   0   0    0
3  2015     2      Ca       0  0   159703  2    36131   5   0    0
4  2015     2      Ch   88289  1 11227345  3  4305786   2   0    0
5  2015     2      Fu       0  0   794601  1        0   0   0    0
6  2015     2      Zu       0  0    70818  1   218310   9   0    0
7  2015     3      Ca       0  0    93577  1     9586   3   0    0
8  2015     3      Ch       0  0 11114302  3  1149480   4   0    0
9  2015     3      Fu       0  0   847562  1        0   0   0    0
10 2015     3      Zu       0  0   229086  2        0   1   0    0
11 2015     4      Ca       0  0    59999  1     9375   3   0    0
12 2015     4      Ch       0  0  9927702  3 16706470   8   0    0
13 2015     4      Fu       0  0  1000049  1    84655   2   0    0
14 2015     4      Zu       0  0   173894  1    74300   2   0    0
```

also, here is raw data

```
year,month,company,wp,wn,ep,en,pa,pan,npa,npan
2015,1,Ch,6497985,1,1471586,2,4833118,3,0,0
2015,1,SK,350,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
2015,2,Ca,0,0,159703,2,36131,5,0,0
2015,2,Ch,88289,1,11227345,3,4305786,2,0,0
2015,2,Fu,0,0,794601,1,0,0,0,0
2015,2,Zu,0,0,70818,1,218310,9,0,0
2015,3,Ca,0,0,93577,1,9586,3,0,0
2015,3,Ch,0,0,11114302,3,1149480,4,0,0
2015,3,Fu,0,0,847562,1,0,0,0,0
2015,3,Zu,0,0,229086,2,0,1,0,0
2015,4,Ca,0,0,59999,1,9375,3,0,0
2015,4,Ch,0,0,9927702,3,16706470,8,0,0
2015,4,Fu,0,0,1000049,1,84655,2,0,0
2015,4,Zu,0,0,173894,1,74300,2,0,0
```

I want to display the plot *(test$ep)* ordered by *year and month(xaxis)*, and the plot contains all companies. ***SOLVED*** maybe other users have similar question in the future. I post my way in the following.

> test$year <- as.Date(test$year)  
>     time_series <- xts(test$ep, order.by = test$year)  
>     dygraph(time_series , group = test$company)

However, the plot did not show anything.

My solving way:

> test$year <- as.yearmon(test$year , "%m %Y)  
>     testre <- dcast(test, year~company ,value.var = "ep")  
>     testre[is.na(testre)] <- 0  
>     test_xts <- xts(testre[,-1], order.by = testre$year)  
>     dygraph(test_xts)

**very appreciate.**  
thanks for this platform so I can ask questions and learn many things from other kind users.

Comment: Can you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @Samuel Ok. I edited my question. Please help me. very appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something to help you started. Assuming `test` is your data frame, you should first (while as you did) convert from long to wide. Once your shiny app is running, select several rows in your `DT` table.

```
library(dygraphs)
library(xts)
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(

      DT::dataTableOutput("x6"),
  tags$br(),
  tags$br(),
      dygraphOutput("dygraph")
  )


server = function(input, output) {

  output$x6 <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({

    test   

  }))


  output$dygraph <- renderDygraph({
    test_select <- test %>% select(year, month, company, ep)
    test_select <- test_select[c(input$x6_rows_selected), ]

    test_select_wide <- dcast(test_select, year + month ~ company, value.var="ep")

    test_select_wide$Date <- as.yearmon(paste(test_select_wide$year, test_select_wide$month, sep = "-"))
    test_select_wide$Date <- as.Date(test_select_wide$Date)

    test_select_wide$year <- NULL
    test_select_wide$month <- NULL
    #test_select_wide <- test_select_wide[,c(6,1,2,3,4,5)]

    test_select_wide_xts <- xts(test_select_wide[,-ncol(test_select_wide)], order.by=test_select_wide[,ncol(test_select_wide)])

    dygraph(test_select_wide_xts)
  })


}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: thank u.  
however, I got some trouble.
Warning: Error in <-: dims [product 1] do not match the length of object [0]
Stack trace (innermost first):
    80: cast
    79: dcast
    78: func [C:\Users\PECHEN\Desktop/server.R#18]
    77: origRenderFunc
    76: output$dygraph
     1: runApp

Comment: @Peter, I understand what you mean. I did a small edit to my answer, but these (warning) errors are normal because of the is line: test_select_wide <- dcast(test_select, year + month ~ company, value.var="ep") and also because there is no pts when you initially ask to draw the graph